# How to pass a Path object to a new Activity (Android)

Tags: android

In my current activity I have a Path object that the user has created by drawing on the screen with their finger. I'd like to pass this Path object on to the next activity, presumably via an Intent.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, TrainingActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("image",byteArray);

/* Pass the Path to the Intent here*/

// Start new activity with this new intent
activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```

I have tried using the approximate() method to approximate the path as an array of points like so

```
float[] pArray = path.approximate(0.5);
myIntent.putExtra("arr",pArray);
```

However android gives me the error: "cannot resolve method 'approximate(double)' ", and for some reason I can't get it to work so this method seems to be a no go.

Comment: yes, `android.graphics.Path` has no such public / visible method - it is hidden by `@hide` annotation

Comment: According to docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#approximate(float)), this method is only available in Android O preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody has this same question in the future, the solution I came up with was to record the x and y coordinates whenever somebody touched the screen, as I was building the Path. I place these coordinates into an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Float> xCoords = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> yCoords = new ArrayList<Float>();

 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Get the coordinates of the touch event
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // When a finger touches down on the screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Add the coordinates to array lists
                xCoords.add(eventX);
                yCoords.add(eventY);
                // Set a new starting point
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            // When a finger moves around on the screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                xCoords.add(eventX);
                yCoords.add(eventY);
                // Connect the points
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
           ...
           ...
           ...
```

Then to pass these points that compose the Path on to the next Activity, I simply add the two arrays as extras to an Intent and pass that Intent to the new Activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, TrainingActivity.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("image",byteArray);

// Add the two arrays with points
myIntent.putExtra("Xpoints",xCoords);
myIntent.putExtra("Ypoints",yCoords);

// Start new activity with this new intent
activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then if you really need a Path object, simply create a new Path using these points.